# How to access single integer from JSONArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have converted a jsonobject to jsonarray which contains these numbers seperated by commas `[12,20,26,25,89,92,30,16]` (Example numbers)
How can I access each number individually and treat it as an integer?

```
JSONObject JA = new JSONObject(data);
        for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jobj1 = (JSONObject) JA.get("today");
                JSONObject jobj2 = jobj1.getJSONObject("Numbers");
                JSONArray jarray_list = jobj2.getJSONArray("list");

                Log.d(TAG, "Numbers = " + jarray_list);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use split() function to convert the string to array of individual numbers. Then use Integer.parseInt() to convert them to integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply parse it.

```
String data = jarray_list.toString();
// omit [ & ]
data = data.substring(1, data.length() - 1);
String[] strNums = data.split(",");

for (String item : strNums) {
    int parsed = Integer.parseInt(item);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the split()-method -> Iterator or simple for-loop to access them -> Integer.parseInt(String s) to parse them/handle them as int